# String.difference(secondString) Acting Like String.same(secondString)

Tags: apex, string

`keyString.difference(leadDisqAccountsMap.get(key).Name)` below seems to yield not the strings' differences, but their equivalents!  Please see my debug log following the code.

```
    String keyString = 'text';
    for(String key : leadDisqAccountsMap.keySet() ){
        keyString = keyString +' '+leadDisqAccountsMap.get(key).Name;
    }                    

    for(Lead l : changedRecords){
        String disqAccs = '';
        Integer x = 1;
        if( leadDisqAccountsMap.containsKey(l.FirstName+' '+l.LastName) || 
            leadDisqAccountsMap.containsKey(l.Company) || 
            leadDisqAccountsMap.containsKey(l.Street) ){ 

            for(String key : leadDisqAccountsMap.keySet() ){  
                String stringDifference = keyString.difference( leadDisqAccountsMap.get(key).Name );

                if(key == l.FirstName+' '+l.LastName || 
                   key == l.Company || 
                   key == l.Street && !stringDifference.contains(leadDisqAccountsMap.get(key).Name) ){

                   System.debug(keyString);
                   System.debug(leadDisqAccountsMap.get(key).Name);
                   System.debug(stringDifference);  
                   System.debug( !stringDifference.contains(leadDisqAccountsMap.get(key).Name) );
```

[image]

Comment: You should verify you are not being misled by a trailing or leading space in the strings being "diff'd"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way i observed the behaviour for this method is:

It truncates the words from the beginning of the parameter in the difference method.

List of outputs below:

```
String s1 = 'test Acme test 3';
String s2 = 'test 3';
System.debug(s2.difference(s1)); //output: 'Acme test 3'
//Finds 'test' in String s1 in the beginning and removes it

String s1 = 'test Acme test 3';
String s2 = 'Acme';
System.debug(s2.difference(s1)); //output: 'test Acme test 3'
//Does not find 'Acme' in the starting characters of String S1. So did not remove anything
```

In your case, the String does not start with 'Acme'. So it does not return any difference. Interesting though that the method is not smart enough for your use-case.